# Как запретить чтение файла через bash или cmd?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, shell

Пробую запретить доступ на чтение всем

```
chmod a=--- file.txt
```

Не срабатывает.

По `ls -l` права на файл по прежнему `-r--r--r--`

Как это можно исправить?
Окружение `ОС Windows 7 x64`, `bash shell`.

UPD. Вариант chmod a-r увы не сработал

```
user@Lenovo MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Новая папка
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 0 мар  9 18:18 test.txt

user@Lenovo MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Новая папка
$ chmod a-r test.txt

user@Lenovo MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Новая папка
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 0 мар  9 18:18 test.txt
```

Comment: `chmod a-r` например

Comment: Увы. Этот вариант не сработал
Листинг кода в UPD к вопроса..

Comment: Так у вас windows, только сейчас обратил на это внимание. Думаю права доступа под win эмулируются, потому что под win совсем другая система прав (нет например понятия пользователь, группа, остальные) и что то мне подсказывает, что вам надо править в самой винде NTFS права, а никсовый chmod этого просто не умеет

Comment: `icacls` пробовал?

Comment: Это напрямую зависит от исходной файловой системы. Поверх этого, как уже выше сказали, слой эмуляции, который тоже может не всё поддерживать.